# How can I delete a item from an array and push a result?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have this array:

```
 [
  {
   "id": "z12",
   "val": "lu",
   "val2": "1",
  },
  {
   "id": "z13",
   "val": "la",
   "val2": "2",
  },
  {
   "id": "z14",
   "val": "lo",
   "val2": "3",
  },
]
```

I have second

```
    array2 = {
      tab: [],
    }
```

i do in my typeScript :

```
   array.forEach((item, index)=>{
    if(item.id === z12){
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }else{
      array2.tab.push(item.id);
    }
});
```

I should normally have: tab: [z13,z14] but it does not work

Comment: you might want to look at [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: If you splice an entry from within an array you are currently passing to the `forEach()`, the `forEach()` routine will skip the next entry. To prevent this behavior use `array.slice().forEach(...)` which creates a copy of the original array. `Array.prototype.filter()` generates a new reference in the memory but may be the routine you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter and map directly.

```js
const array = [{ "id": "z12", "val": "lu", "val2": "1", }, { "id": "z13", "val": "la", "val2": "2", }, { "id": "z14", "val": "lo", "val2": "3", },];

const array2 = {
  tab: array.filter(e => e['id'] != "z12").map(e => e['id']),
}

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make it in two steps:

```js
// first remove the "z12" from the array as you requested
array = array.filter(e => e.id !== 'z12')

// and second get the remaining ids
array2 = {
  tab: array.map(e => e.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

splice() method in forEach() cause the problem
when the "z12" was removed, the array became

```js
 [
  {
   "id": "z13",
   "val": "la",
   "val2": "2",
  },
  {
   "id": "z14",
   "val": "lo",
   "val2": "3",
  },
]
```

**BUT** the iteration of forEach method did not stop itself.
it will continue with index of 1 that just after the z12 was removed
so the index of 1 is the "z14", not the "z13".

some knowledge of forEach
[forEach is BAD!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lqJBBEpjRE)